# Excel Graph with 2 X-Axis Non-Linear Mapping

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have the following problem someone might be able to help with.

I have two risk scales, one from 1 to 11 (old) and one from 1 to 21 (new), where the mapping is non-linear, i.e. old scale->new scale = 1->1, 2->{2,3,4,5},3->{6,7,8},4->{9,10},5->{11,12},6->{13,14,15},7->16,8->{17,18},9->19,10->20,11->21.

I want to show how users are distributed according to the old risk grade and the new risk grade in one graph and have no clue on how to do it.

Here is a sketch of what I'm looking for:

[image: Sketch of chart]

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: A simple scatter plot of new risk vs old risk won't work?  If not, I think you're leaving something important out of your question -- can you explain more what you want the chart to look like?

Comment: The problem is that to make it visually easy to compare I don't want all the old stuff on one side. otherwise it looks like the risk profile has been shifted, which it has not. It just added granularity to some of the risk grades (but not others). So ideally I want the 1 to align with the 1, and the 9 with the 19 etc which wouldn't work in a scatter plot. Or would it?

Comment: So you have a set of data for the y-axis? But, you want two different x-axes, one with the new risk data and one with the old?

Comment: Correct. Y-axis data are simple counts.

Comment: Are you okay with having the new and old risk factors stacked together in a single x-axis in a histogram?  I'm having a hard time picturing what you're looking for. Could you sketch it in Paint or something, and add the pic to your question?

Comment: Sorry, not enough reputation to post images apparently :/

Comment: Received your email. Will edit the question with your image soon.  Do you want the old risk plotted at the left edge of each range (2 on 2, 3 on 6, 4 on 9, 5 on 11, etc.), or do you want the old risk centered relative to the new risk  (2 on 3.5, 3 on 7, 4 on 9.5, 5 on 11.5, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Based upon your example, is this what you're looking to accomplish?

[image: New Image based upon Example]

One way to accomplish this is to chart your risk values in a standard column chart.  Then add a custom Y Axis, made up of 2 XY series (one for your old scale and one for your new).  The effect could be something like this:

[image: 2 Y Axis]

Or, you could have grid lines for your new values:

[image: 2 Y Axis_2]

Answer (score 0):

**Ok, here's what I've come up with:**

[image: Risk comparison chart]

**The source data looks like this:**

[image: Excel source]

Not having your dataset, I just generated one based on a lightly randomized normal distribution.  The 'new risk' data is a simple column chart on the Primary axes.  The 'old risk' data is a scatter plot on Secondary axes.  I started out by putting both 'old' and 'new' data as column chart series.  Then (in Excel 2010) I single-left-clicked the 'old' series, then right-clicked it, then chose "Change Series Chart Type", and finally switched it to Scatter.  I left the x-axis data blank for the 'old risk' data after switching to Scatter:

[image: Edit series dialog]

I selected the 'wide line' type of marker and increased the marker size to 12:

[image: Marker selection]

Finally, I added data labels to the 'old' series, deleted all but the left-most label for each old-risk value (single-left-click the data labels to select the whole group; then single-left-click each undesired label and press <kbd>Delete</kbd>), and manually edited the labels to show the 'old risk' values  (when an individual data label is selected, single-left-click again to edit its text).

Taking a final look at the chart, I would probably remove the legend and add a textbox with red text that says "Old Risk Factor".